# SQL count and sum issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with data.

The first table `cus` contains the customer data. The second table `invoice` contains the invoices created by the customer.

I want to select the total created invoices and the total sum of the invoices per customer.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT cus.cus_id, cus.name_cus, count(invoice.id) as id2, CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(SUM(invoice.total),2)) as total, cus.id 
FROM cus 
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice ON cus.cus_id = invoice.cus_id 
WHERE cus.user_id='2' 
GROUP BY cus.cus_id
```

To test this I have added some data to my database. The first customer has 2 invoices with a total sum of 100 (50+50).
The second customer has 3 invoices with a total sum of 30 (10+10+10).

But the SQL code dont shows me these results.

The response is for customer 1: total invoices = 1, total = 50
The response is for customer 1: total invoices = 0, total = (empty)

Does someone know what is wrong with my SQL statement?

The database type I am using is MySQL.

Here is a sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9f9f/1

Comment: Not sure which type of DB this is but I'm surprised it runs as is. you are selecting columns that aren't in the group by. Also your where clause is using cus.user_id rather than cus_id

Comment: The database is mysql. user_id is something else. For both customers the `user_id = '2'`

Comment: Can you provide sample data? You state that customer 2 has 3 invoices. Can we that style of data. Seems to the issue is data related and/or your join logic is incorrect.

Comment: Do you know a site like jsfiddle where I can insert the sample data

Comment: Here is a sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9f9f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping up your invoice count and sum as a subquery first, like:

```
SELECT cus.cus_id, cus.name_cus, inv.invoice_count, inv.invoice_total, cus.id
FROM cus
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT inv.cus_id, 
    COUNT(inv.id) AS invoice_count,
    CONCAT('€ ', ROUND(SUM(inv.total),2)) AS invoice_total
    FROM invoice inv
    GROUP BY inv.cus_id
) inv
ON cus.cus_id = inv.cus_id
WHERE cus.user_id='2'
```

Comment: I get: `#1064 - There is something wrong in the syntax at 'FROM invoice
  WHERE cus.user_id='2'
  GROUP BY cus.cus_id
) in
O' on line 7`

Comment: I still get the same response: `The response is for customer 1: total invoices = 1, total = 50 The response is for customer 1: total invoices = 0, total = (empty)`

Comment: Try again, inner where clause was causing problem with MySQL.  Thanks for the excellent SQLFiddle sample.

Comment: Gordon. Your edited statement works in SQLFiddle. But in my mysql database the result is still the same

Comment: What it's incorrect in you results, rows returned, invoice_count, invoice_total?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server then your query should be like this --

```
SELECT C.cus_id
    ,C.name_cus
    ,Count(I.id) AS NumberOfInvoices
    ,IsNull(Sum(I.Price), 0) AS TotalPrice
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Invoice I ON C.cus_id = I.cus_id
GROUP BY C.cus_id, C.name_cus
ORDER BY C.cus_id;
```

Comment: No, I am using MySQL

Comment: For mySQL use COALESCE() or IFNULL() instead of ISNULL()

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple sql Query as i understood your problem. I assumed CustomerID is in both tables. I think this Query will help you.

select i.CustomerID,i.CustomerName,COUNT(i.InvoiceID) as A, SUM(i.invoicetotal) as b
from Cus c,Invoice i
where i.CustomerID=c.CustomerID
group by i.CustomerID

Comment: What is the difference with my statement?